# How to prefix backslash to output

Tags: string, tr

This is my input file.

```
3400,2
3400,27
3400,DC
3400,TF
5600,KA
5600,KN
5600,TF
0313,EX
0313,EY
0313,EZ
0313,FD
0313,FE
0313,JB
0313,JC
0313,KG
0313,T8
```

I want my output to be

```
400,2\|3400,27\|3400,DC\|3400,TF\|5600,KA\|5600,KN\|5600,TF\|0313,EX\|0313,EY\|0313,EZ\|0313,FD\|0313,FE\|0313,JB\|0313,JC\|0313,KG\|0313,T8
```

I am running the code as follows:

```
cat f.txt | tr '\n' "\|"
3400,2|3400,27|3400,DC|3400,TF|5600,KA|5600,KN|5600,TF|0313,EX|0313,EY|0313,EZ|0313,FD|0313,FE|0313,JB|0313,JC|0313,KG|0313,T8

cat f.txt | tr '\n' "\\\|"
3400,2\3400,27\3400,DC\3400,TF\5600,KA\5600,KN\5600,TF\0313,EX\0313,EY\0313,EZ\0313,FD\0313,FE\0313,JB\0313,JC\0313,KG\0313,T8
```

How can I reach my expected output ?

Comment: You could do the following ways: `perl -0777pe 's/\n(?!\z)/\\|/g' f.txt`  `perl -pe 'eof || s/\n/\\|/' f.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in many ways, with many tools, e.g. with `awk` like this:

```
cat f.txt | awk 'BEGIN{ORS="\\|"}1'
```

@don_cristi remarked correctly, that "This will print a trailing \| and no trailing newline", so here is a version that fixes both, if that is needed for your use-case:

```
awk 'p{printf "%s\\|",p} {p=$0} END{print p}'
```

Comment: @don_crissti Good catch, I will correct my answer.